# Can I use IronPython in Visual Studio 2017 and create Ironpython WPF application that passes custom property variables to Solidworks?

Tags: api, visual-studio-2017, ironpython, solidworks

I'm creating my own WPF application on Visual Studio 2017 using IronPython 2.7.9. I would like to connect to active Solidworks Application and pass custom property values as strings to the active part or assembly.

The WPF Application would check what file is open. After this it updates to the application values that are already written as custom properties to the application. By modifying these values and saving, I would write them to the Solidworks part or assembly.

My first step is to create a connection to the running Solidworks, get active document file name and show it on my application on textbox.

First problem that I came in contact with was that there is no information on correct way of connecting to Solidworks application on IronPython. As it is, IronPython does not support early binding that is referred to in Solidworks API. Solidworks comes with its own API DLL-files.

I have used Visual Studio 2017 Ironpython WPF Application project.
I have added a search path for the `\SOLIDWORKS\api\redist` in Solution explorer.
After that I have started the code:

```
python

import clr

clr.AddReference("SldWorks.Interop.sldworks")

import SldWorks.Interop.sldworks as SldWorks

swApp = SldWorks.SldWorks   # Get from here the active document

swModel = SldWorks.ModelDoc2   # Get string through GetTitle() from here

print(swModel.GetTitle(swApp.ActiveDoc))
```

I'm expecting this to get from active Solidworks session an active document title. Then print this.

When running through IronPython 2.7 interactive window with defined `sys.path.append`, the last line gave `TypeError: expected IModelDoc2, got getset_descriptor`.

Update: So far I've worked my way to this type of code. Create a class that inherits ModelDoc2 class properties:

```
import clr
import sys
import System

sys.path.append(r"C:\Program Files\SOLIDWORKS Corp\SOLIDWORKS\api\redist")
clr.AddReference("SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks")
import SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks as SldWorks


class ModelDoc(SldWorks.ModelDoc2):
   def getActiveDocumentTitle(self):
      self.str = SldWorks.ModelDoc2.GetTitle(SldWorks.IModelDoc2)
      return self.str

 swApp = ModelDoc()
 print(swApp.getActiveDocumentTitle())
```

Problem is still the same. I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<string>", line 3, in getActiveDocumentTitle
 TypeError: expected IModelDoc2, got type
```

SOLIDWORKS is a COM-based API that uses:

```
Interfaces

Interface inheritance

Factory methods to return interfaces on existing and new objects

Casting between interfaces through:
    QueryInterface (C++), which returns a pointer to a specified interface on an object to which a client currently holds an interface pointer.
    direct assignment (VB/VB.NET).
    the is/as reserved words (C#).
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be something like this:

```
import clr
import sys
import System

sys.path.append(r"C:\Program Files\SOLIDWORKS Corp\SOLIDWORKS\api\redist")
clr.AddReference("SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks")
import SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks as SldWorks

swApp = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("SldWorks.Application")
swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
print(swModel.GetTitle())
```

Here is similar working code on C#

```
    SldWorks swApp;
    swApp = (SldWorks)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("SldWorks.Application");
    //swApp = (SldWorks)Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("SldWorks.Application"));
    ModelDoc2 doc = swApp.ActiveDoc;
    var str = doc.GetTitle();
    Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Please also take a look at this post with useful info regarding access to SolidWorks from standalone app: https://forum.solidworks.com/thread/215594

Comment: Running your recommended code throws an error: _>>>swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc'_ _'EnviromentError:System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMExpcetion (0x8002802B): Element not found.'_

Comment: This has been discussed on similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924470/using-iron-python-with-solidworks-api)